# Why same .net program run on windows outperforms same program run on linux?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, windows, benchmarking

I am benchmarking some very simple non IO operations on windows-x64 and ubuntu.x64.

Given same HW, same load, etc.. Windows outperforms and runs around 30% faster.

The operations I benchmark are Json serialise/deserialise, basic and concurrent collection lookup, addition, deletion, etc..

The way I build the linux program is using command line

> dotnet publish App.sln —-framework net6.0 —-configuration Release
> -—runtime ubuntu.20.04-x64

I have read in some blogs that this is typical and nothing to be surprised about.   Can someone please confirm or deny or give a clue what’s happening?

Comment: could you provide some more details, for example 1) _what_ the application is doing (=code? are you using async/threads/etc?), 2) how you're building for windows, 3) how you're benchmarking, and what the _exact_ benchmark numbers are, and 4) which blogs that might be?

Comment: There are a very large number of reasons for this. For instance, the thread scheduler on Windows is extremely well written and tends to outperform all of its competitors. The runtime on Windows will almost always run faster than elsewhere because Windows has a native understanding of the CIL and runtime IL. In addition, Windows might be a bug filled mess but at the end of the day tens of thousands of the best programmers this world has ever known came together to build it. It will likely outperform open source written by randos.

Comment: Not trying to disparage Linux by any means, but Windows does have its place in this world for a reason... you just figured out what that reason is.

Comment: Linux was not meant to be faster than Windows. It's meant to be free. So that you can allocate that budget on buying a bigger CPU that should be 30% faster.